# How to disable all firewall rules and SElinux if runs on CentOS7

Tags: firewall, selinux, nis

I try to connect a NIS server on CentOS 7.3 and a NIS client on raspbian 8.0 together.

My problem is that raspbian does not want to bind the server.
`journalctl` server the following entry:

```
raspberrypi nis[708]: Starting NIS services: ypbindbinding to YP server...........................................failed (backgrounded).
```

If I configure raspbian to be the NIS server and the NIS client also, ypwhich command bring good result, it shows the hostname of itself (raspberrypi) and log entry does not exist I mentioned above. When I change back to NIS client mode only, and set up the configuration to look the server on CentOS 7, ypwhich says that the domain just not connected.

After readind several how to-s, I found someone's advice that firewall and SELINUX rules should be checked also.

I'm inexperienced with doing this.
Can someone give the commands how to disable the firewall and/or SELINUX rule against NIS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this command

```
setenforce 0
```

the restart the ybind service

```
 service ypbind stop
 service ypbind start
```

if it doesnt work then the firewall on the NIS server is blocking all connections from the NIS client. you can stop it using

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

to disable it or

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

to stop it

you can check the status of firewalld using the following command:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

Comment: That worked for me. Firewall kept the connection back. After stopping firewall, NIS just works fine. Thank you!